# Updating a page using ajax if the content differs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a voting application, and i need some help.

The problem i'm having is that, i'm sending the request every 3 seconds, and all the choices selected in the form resets on each reload. (Thus the user would have to make a choice and submit it within 3 seconds.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#respnseDiv').load('response.php');
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

This is what i'm currently using to populate the `div`

i want jquery to check the content of each response to see if is the same as the last one, if it is, dont update the div, if the content differs(i.e a new question to vote on), load it into the div.

I'm not very good at js/jquery but eager to learn

Regards

Johan

Comment: try and add some code to your question to make it clearer

Comment: Added the jquery i'm using, i'm not at my computer right now, so i dont have access to my php code atm

Comment: If i understand well, you want to cache the response of the user to the question. Simply store the last answer in a variable, and cross check it when the user attempt to give a new response.

Comment: I might have been a bit unclear, i want jquery to check the content of each response to see if is the same as the last one, if it is, dont update the div, if the content differs(i.e a new question to vote on), load it into the div. @Mysteryos

Answer (score 2):

You could add a hidden input called "id" (that is, containing the id of the question) or something to your div, then create another (hidden) div, to which ajax loads the response. Simply compare the value of "id" inputs, and if they don't match, then you can actually load the html into your original div. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#hiddenDiv').load('response.php');
            if ($("#hiddenDiv input.id").val() != $('#respnseDiv input.id').val())
            {
                $('#respnseDiv').html($('#hiddenDiv').html());
            }               
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use timestamps in your mysql table and then make another php file for checking the latest timestamp with your conditions. check for this timestamp and save the timestamp of the latest db-update in a javascript variable.

```
var latest_timestamp = 0;

setInterval(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "check_timestamp.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(latest_db_timestamp){
            if(latest_timestamp < latest_db_timestamp)
            {
                $('#respnseDiv').load('response.php');
            }
        }
    });

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a global var to compare each response to the last response, and modify html only if there's a difference.

here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var last_response = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function() {
            var res = $.get('response.php');
            if (res != last_response) {
                $('#respnseDiv').html(res);
                last_response = res;
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

hope that helps.

Comment: This seems to be what i'm looking for, will try it asap